# MySQL latency caused by using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

Tags: mysql

I have a query that joins two tables and orders the data on the primary key. This is resulting in the very popular problem of MySQL "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort."

The issue is causing a severe latency problem in my production tables with about 400k records.

Here's more info:

I have two tables: Doctor and Area. The Doctor table has a foreign key pointing to Area.

Doctor:

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| area_id                     | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Doctor indexes:

```
+---------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| doctor        |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id               | A         |        5546 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| doctor        |          1 | doctor_dfd0e917        |            1 | area_id          | A         |          29 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Area:

```
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the Area indexes:

```
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| area          |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT `doctor`.`id`, 
       `area`.`id` 
FROM 
       `doctor` 
INNER JOIN 
       `area` ON (`doctor`.`area_id` = `area`.`id`) 
ORDER BY 
      `doctor`.`id` DESC LIMIT 100;
```

The EXPLAIN returns the following (with the problematic Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort):

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys          | key                    | key_len | ref          | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | area          | index | PRIMARY                | PRIMARY                | 4       | NULL         |   24 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | doctor        | ref   | doctor_dfd0e917        | doctor_dfd0e917        | 4       | area.id      |  191 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

If I remove the ORDER BY clause, I get the desired effect:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys          | key                    | key_len | ref          | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | area          | index | PRIMARY                | PRIMARY                | 4       | NULL         |   24 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | doctor        | ref   | doctor_dfd0e917        | doctor_dfd0e917        | 4       | area.id      |  191 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Why is the ORDER BY clause causing problems here even though I'm using the primary key?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why `Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort` is a problem of any sorts, I'll just make a guess that you *think* it is. Your issue is in disk I/O, that's what I'm 100% sure about. Long story short - for queries that deal with potentially large tables (or for entire MySQL servers), we prefer to have working dataset in RAM so we can avoid these issues caused by slow disk seeks. This means increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value so it can allocate more RAM. Another guess - you're running the default 8 megabyte buffer pool? `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb_buffer%;`.

Comment: @N.B. Here's what I see: innodb_buffer_pool_size  1179648000

Comment: No, your problem is the very popular "reading all the rows in the database" issue

Comment: @symcbean: Got it. Any thoughts on the fix?

Comment: Ok, that's roughly ~1.2gb. Is your dataset larger than that? You're also scanning the entire table with the query, you read all of it then discard everything minus 100 rows - that's how `LIMIT` works. You either increase the buffer pool to stick all the data in RAM, or you use dirty tricks by letting the engine scan only the portion of data.

Comment: @N.B. The dataset is currently 150MB.

Comment: Silly question - are the tables InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: @N.B. The tables are InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only have one area per doctor.  See how this query works:

```
SELECT d.id,
       (SELECT a.id FROM area a ON a.id = d.area_id) as area_id
FROM doctor d 
ORDER BY d.id DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

If you are using `inner join` to test for the presence of a doctor in the table, then add:

```
SELECT d.id,
       (SELECT a.id FROM area a ON a.id = d.area_id) as area_id
FROM doctor d 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM area a ON a.id = d.area_id)
ORDER BY d.id DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

There is a good chance that both of these will scan the `doctors` table in order, picking up the information from `area` as needed.

Comment: Thanks. You're right that I only have one area per doctor, but there are many Areas and each Doctor can have a different one. Your subquery doesn't work because it returns more than one row.

Comment: @AbidA  . . . Then you would use `limit 1` or an aggregation function, such as `group_concat()`.